# Safely save a dictionary to file

Tags: character-encoding, tcl

What's the best way to save a dictionary to a file, so that I can load it later in Tcl on a different computer/system?

I don't think `fconfigure $stream -translation binary; puts -nonewline $stream $dict` works if there's keys/values with unicode characters > \u00ff. Is "utf-8" encoding OK (to save disk space), or should I always use full "unicode"?

Dictionaries are new to me, but since their textual representation is that of a list with alternating keys/values, and a list is just a string with some extra syntax characters, maybe the question could've been "Safely save a *string* to file"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be simplified:

> What encoding should I use?

The answer is: it depends.

- If you have only binary data, then binary is the way to go.
- If you have mostly ascii chars and a few exceptions (like umlauts etc), then utf-8 ist the best encoding for you (characters outside of `\x00` and `\x7f` are encoded with 2 or more bytes, ascii with 1 byte).
- If you have many [CJK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK), then using unicode or some other encoding for that is probably better (2 byte vs 3 byte per char)

And right: the (de)serialization of lists and dicts is in Tcl much easier than in many other languages: Save it as string.

Comment: Also, if you use anything other than the system encoding then you'll need to take special care in many places to deal with it (i.e., in anything that reads it back into memory). If the data is going to be processed by non-Tcl code, **really** stick to the system encoding to keep the “WTF!?” factor down.